# using endsWith(), question from R4DS learner

Tags: r, select, dplyr, ends-with

This is my first attempted reprex. I am working through R for Data Science. I am trying to narrow down a data frame to then be able to mutate it, but having trouble with the `endsWith()` function I think. When I run this section of the code I get the following error message. You can see that when I then change to (x, "delay") I get a different message. I am not sure how to deal with either and would love some help. Also, I'm not sure why, but `dplyr::select()` is working for me (as an example), while select() is not, so that's why it's different than the book. Thanks!

```r
flights_sml <- dplyr::select(flights,
         year:day,
         endsWith("delay"),
         distance,
         air_time
       )
```

> Error: argument "suffix" is missing, with no default
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

```r
flights_sml <- dplyr::select(flights,
         year:day,
         endsWith(x, "delay"),
         distance,
         air_time
       )
```

> Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
> x Subscript has the wrong type `logical`.
> ℹ It must be numeric or character.

Comment: tipo: `ends_with` is from `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1):

Good start. The [tidy-select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) function is ends_with, while the base r function is [endsWith](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/startsWith.html)

```r
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)


flights_sml<-flights %>%
  select(year:day,ends_with("delay"),distance,air_time)

flights_sml
#> # A tibble: 336,776 × 7
#>     year month   day dep_delay arr_delay distance air_time
#>    <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1  2013     1     1         2        11     1400      227
#>  2  2013     1     1         4        20     1416      227
#>  3  2013     1     1         2        33     1089      160
#>  4  2013     1     1        -1       -18     1576      183
#>  5  2013     1     1        -6       -25      762      116
#>  6  2013     1     1        -4        12      719      150
#>  7  2013     1     1        -5        19     1065      158
#>  8  2013     1     1        -3       -14      229       53
#>  9  2013     1     1        -3        -8      944      140
#> 10  2013     1     1        -2         8      733      138
#> # … with 336,766 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I think that's "tidyselect" (not `tidy_select`)

Comment: Thank you! edited above, with additional links...

Comment: Thanks all! I thought I had tried that (that's what was assigned) but apparently not!